# Unable to reflect the data from Firebase to Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, I have this data type decision and the app is about making decisions. There is a section for decided decisions in which you can decide to re-decide or delete the decision. I fetch the decisions with this code using Firebase:

```
class decisionObserver : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var decisions = [Decision]()
    
    let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    
    init() {
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection(userId!).getDocuments { (snap, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err!.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            for i in snap!.documents {
                
                let id = i.documentID
                let text = i.get("text") as! String
                let type = i.get("type") as! String
                let timestamp : Timestamp = i.get("dueDate") as! Timestamp
                let dueDate = timestamp.dateValue()
                let isDecided = i.get("isDecided") as! Bool
                let isPositive = i.get("isPositive") as! Bool
                let offset = i.get("offset") as! CGFloat
                
                self.decisions.append(Decision(id: id, text: text, type: type, dueDate: dueDate, isDecided: isDecided, isPositive: isPositive, offset: offset))
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
}
```

And in order to delete a decision, I use this code.

```
db.collection(userId!).document(decision.id).delete { (err) in
    if let err = err {
        print(err)
    }
    else {
        print("Succesfully removed")
        self.deleteOffset = 1000
        self.decisionData.decisions.remove(at: decisionIndex)
    }
}
```

The user gets to delete a decision after pressing on it for 2 seconds. Once the deletetion is done he can click the done button and go back to the normal view. But in that view the deleted decisions stays as the function to fet decisions is not being recalled. What could be a good way to re-fetch the data once deletion is done?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getDocuments`, consider using `addSnapshotListener` to read the documents. With `addSnapshotListener` you will still get the same behavior as now, but it will then continue to [observe the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen). And whenever there's a relevant change in the database, your closure it called with that new data, so you can update `self.decisions` and the UI.

So it'd look something like:

```
db.collection(userId!).addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in
    if err != nil {
        print(err!.localizedDescription)
    }
    self.decisions.removeAll()
    for i in snap!.documents {
        
        let id = i.documentID
        let text = i.get("text") as! String
        let type = i.get("type") as! String
        let timestamp : Timestamp = i.get("dueDate") as! Timestamp
        let dueDate = timestamp.dateValue()
        let isDecided = i.get("isDecided") as! Bool
        let isPositive = i.get("isPositive") as! Bool
        let offset = i.get("offset") as! CGFloat
        
        self.decisions.append(Decision(id: id, text: text, type: type, dueDate: dueDate, isDecided: isDecided, isPositive: isPositive, offset: offset))
    }

    // TODO: tell iOS to update the UI, for example by calling reloadData() on the view
    
}
```